# What do each of these things in the Trello Menu?

Tags: trello

I'm a little confused by the bottom half of the Menu (pictured below), specifically:
 **what is the second highlighted item ( "Bungalow Software PR".)?**

Obviously, I created it, but it was a while ago while playing around with it.
Is that a *collection( of additional boards (so My Boards is one collection, and Bungalow Software PR is another collection)?

Those two (circled) items behave differently from each other and from Boards.My Boards doesn't "highlight" when I mouse over it, but Bungalow... *does*, but neither is clickable)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*As usual, the rigor of trying to define the question pointed me to the answer.
I'm putting it here for posterity.*

The second hilighted item is a different Organization (in our case, the company).
So, in a way, it is a "container" of Boards.